# What type of connector is on this UJ-844 DVD drive?

Tags: connector, identification

This is a DVD multi UJ-844 drive, but I can't identify the connector correctly online.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: photo showing unknown connector]

Comment: what does the multi uj-844 documentation say?

Comment: check for markings on the connector

Answer (score 2):

JAE KX15-50KL. It's supposed to be used with devices that utilize the JAE KX14-50KL socket.